# Add unmanaged bridge to Docker

Tags: docker, network-bridge, vlan

I am setting up a server with Docker and LXD. I have a real network with several vlans which I want to have bridges to, that can be shared between Docker and LXD. This was relatively easy with LXD, but Docker is like that annoying girlfriend wanting to control everything, so I am having difficulty getting it to play nice.

Here are the netplan configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2

  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      match:
        macaddress: 84:a9:3e:86:7b:d4
      set-name: enp5s0

    enx0s0:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:e0:4c:02:61:57
      set-name: enx0s0

  bridges:
    vlan69: # Untagged
      interfaces:
        - enp5s0
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no

    vlan36:
      interfaces:
        - enx0s0.36
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

    vlan32:
      interfaces:
        - enp5s0.32
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

    vlan1:
      interfaces:
        - enp5s0.1
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

  vlans:
    enx0s0.36:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 36
      link: enx0s0

    enp5s0.32:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 32
      link: enp5s0

    enp5s0.1:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 1
      link: enp5s0
```

With LXD this was as easy as simply adding a NIC to one of the vlans.

```
devices:
  enp1s0:
    nictype: bridged
    parent: vlan36
    type: nic
```

But Docker is not that easy to deal with apparently. After hours of searching through sources on docker networks, I came up with this.

```
root@host:~# docker network create vlan32 \
-o com.docker.network.bridge.inhibit_ipv4=true \ 
-o com.docker.network.bridge.name=vlan32 \ 
--subnet=192.168.32.0/24 \
--gateway=192.168.32.254
```

This seamed to do the job just fine. Connecting containers worked fine, they had access to the network, my router could see them connected, pinging other devices on the network was also working, but. You can not establish an incoming connection back to the containers. Pinging a container just results in an unreachable network. And this is not just affecting Docker but also LXD. So even though Docker seams to simply adopt the bridge, it does something to it. Disabling the Docker service and rebooting fixes the problem for the LXD containers.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To provide some additional information regarding your issue, can you please include the version of Ubuntu that you're using. Also, the reference to "annoying girlfriend" can be perceived as inappropriate and is not relevant to the issue: please edit.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not seam right, but it works and seams to behave the way I want. Think the issue is that the `bridge` driver does not support `-o parent`. Instead it will just create it's own device.

**netplan**

```
network:
  version: 2

  ethernets:
    <NIC>:
      dhcp4: yes

  bridges:
    vlan<VLAN>:
      interfaces:
        - <NIC>.<VLAN>
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

  vlans:
    <NIC>.<VLAN>:
      accept-ra: no
      id: <VLAN>
      link: <NIC>
```

**LXD**

```
devices:
  enp1s0:
    nictype: bridged
    parent: vlan<VLAN>
```

**Docker**

```
root@host:~# docker network create <NETWORK_NAME> \
            --subnet 192.168.x.x/24 \
            --gateway 192.168.x.254 \
            --driver macvlan \
            -o parent=vlan<VLAN>
```